# MySQL 5.7.7 collation 'hebrew_general_ci' is not valid for character set 'utf8'

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, collation, hebrew

Problem summary: Can't open MySQL 5.7.7 with the following variables:

```
character_set_client    hebrew
character_set_connection    hebrew
character_set_database  hebrew
character_set_filesystem    hebrew
character_set_results   hebrew
character_set_server    hebrew
character_set_system    hebrew
character_sets_dir  C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\share\charsets\
```

What the MYSQL 5.7.7 writes: 'hebrew_general_ci' is not valid for character set 'utf8'

What do I get:

```
character_set_client    utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database  utf8
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8
character_set_server    utf8
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\share\charsets\
```

Software: MySQL 5.7.7

Operating system: WIN 7 64-bit

***What did i do:***
**1. Changed all data in C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\My.ini configuration file to:**

```
[client]
no-beep
default-character-set = hebrew

[mysql]

default-character-set=hebrew

[mysqld]

init_connect='SET collation_connection = hebrew_general_ci'
character-set-server = hebrew
collation-server = hebrew_general_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES hebrew'
init_connect='SET collation_connection = hebrew_general_ci'
```

**2. Ran the server from cmd with:**

```
mysqld --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini"
```

**3. got the error message when running the server from CMD**

```
MySQL 5.7.7 collation 'hebrew_general_ci' is not valid for character set 'utf8'
```

**4. The main issue is that any change in configuration is not occuring **

Comment: Try under [mysqld] keeping just `character-set-server...` and `collation server..` and add `init_connect='SET collation_connection = hebrew_general_ci,NAMES hebrew'`

Comment: Also add or uncomment these lines `character_set_client        = hebrew
character_set_connection    = hebrew
character_set_results       = hebrew
` and restart

Answer (score 1):

The `HEX` for Alef in `CHARACTER SET hebrew` is `F0`; in utf8, it is `D790`.  Check the hex in your application language to see which you have.  Then do `SET NAMES` to `hebrew` or `utf8` accordingly.

```
mysql> SET NAMES hebrew;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                         |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | hebrew                                        |
| character_set_connection | hebrew                                        |
| character_set_database   | latin1                                        |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                        |
| character_set_results    | hebrew                                        |
| character_set_server     | utf8                                          |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                          |
| character_sets_dir       | c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\share\charsets\ |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Notice how `SET NAMES` modifies only 3 of the entries.  It is dangerous to modify any of the others.  Recommend you not change the others.

`SET NAMES` declares to mysql what the encoding is in your *client*.  The encoding in the table can be different.   In particular, since you seem to want `hebrew_general_ci`, the only way to get it (or equivalent, since there seems not to be a utf8_hebrew_ci) is to declare you columns to be `CHARACTER SET hebrew COLLATION hebrew_general_ci`.  Keep in mind that this setting is independent of the enocoding in the client; `SET NAMES` handles conversion if needed.

If the application involves a web page, the meta tag needs to include the *client's* character set.

When connecting as `root`, `init_connect` (in `my.ini`) is skipped.  Hence, you may find confusing results; avoid being root (or any `SUPER` user).

[This collation chart](http://collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.hebrew_general_ci.html) specifies what happens in hebrew_general_ci; it may not be anything special.  My point is -- `utf8` with `utf8_general_ci` may give you identical results.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your fast and informative reply. My application for reading MySQL Tables is SAS9.4. Actually, I'm trying to read the MySQL tables via SAS\ACCESS Interface to MySQL.

After a bit of research, I've changed my SAS cfg file (C:\Program Files\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4\sasv9.cfg)

```
From: -config "C:\Program Files\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4\nls\en\sasv9.cfg"
To: -config "C:\Program Files\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4\nls\u8\sasv9.cfg"
```

Now both of the applications "talk" utf8.

That solved the issue... :)

Thanks a lot!!

Daniel